# Failed to free all used memory

Tags: c, list, linked-list

The autograder is telling me that I failed to free all used memory. I am not sure where I have caused a memory leak so here is my entire code:

```
struct lnode {
int count;
int line;
char* word;
struct lnode* next;
};


struct lnode* newNode(char* word, int line) {
struct lnode* temp = (struct lnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct lnode));
char* newWord = (char*)malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
newWord = strcpy(newWord, word);
temp->word = newWord;
temp->line = line;
temp->count = 1;
return temp;
}

void pushNode(struct lnode** head, struct lnode* node) {
node->next = *head;
*head = node;


}

struct lnode* getNode(struct lnode* head, char* word) {
struct lnode* current = head;
char* temp = (char *)malloc(strlen(word));
strcpy(temp, word);
while(current != NULL) {
    if(!strcmp(nodeGetWord(current),temp)) 
        return current; 

    current = nodeGetNext(current);
}
return NULL;
}

char* nodeGetWord(struct lnode* node) {
return node->word;
}

struct lnode* nodeGetNext(struct lnode* node) {
return node->next;
}

int nodeGetLine(struct lnode* node) {
int line = node->line;
return line;
}

int nodeGetCount(struct lnode* node) {
return node->count;
}

void nodeSetCount(struct lnode* node, int count) {
node->count = count;
}

void nodeSetLine(struct lnode* node, int line) {
node->line = line;
}

void deleteList(struct lnode** head) {
struct lnode* current = *head;
struct lnode* next;
while(current) {
    next = current->next;
    free(current);
    current = next;
}
*head = NULL;

}

void deleteNode(struct lnode** head, struct lnode* node) {
struct lnode* currentNode = *head;
struct lnode* previousNode = NULL;

while (currentNode != NULL) {
    if (currentNode != node) {
        previousNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = nodeGetNext(currentNode);
        continue;
    }

    if (previousNode)
        previousNode->next = node->next;
    else
        *head = node->next;
    free(node);
    break;
}
}

void printList(struct lnode** head) {
struct lnode* current = *head;
while (current != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n",nodeGetWord(current));
    current = nodeGetNext(current);
}

} 
int main() {
struct lnode* head = NULL;

struct lnode* a = newNode("Hello",3);
pushNode(&head, a);
struct lnode* b = newNode("Hi",2);
pushNode(&head, b);
struct lnode* c = newNode("Hola",4);
pushNode(&head, c);
struct lnode* d = newNode("Yo",5);
pushNode(&head, d);
struct lnode* e = newNode("Bye", 7);
pushNode(&head, e);
printList(&head);
//deleteNode(&head,e);
//printf("key: %s\n",nodeGetWord(e));
//printf("\n");
deleteList(&head);
printf("\n");
printList(&head);   
printf("\nDone\n");


}
```

The main and printList() functions can be ignored, because those are commented out when I submit this to the autograder--they are just used for testing purposes. Everything seems to work properly for me. I had even implemented a global integer that would get updated whenever I `malloc` something and decremented whenever something was freed. If someone could point out where a possible memory leak is, that'd be great!

Comment: Don't search. Sketch and think.

Comment: Try imagining you're the computer and see if you can work out what your deleteNode() function will do when you try to remove the head of the list. If your example is too tedious to work through, try a simpler model, where you add one node to your list and then delete that node from the list head. Write down the initial values of passed parameters and local variables and note how they change as you work through your function logic. Working this out the hard way will give you the solution, along with the satisfaction of solving this problem on your own instead of having the answer handed to you.

Comment: Before going through all that drudgery, it's preferable to think conceptually at a much higher level. The OP prints a node that was just deleted from a list and freed; that's obvious UB. The OP has some expectation that deleting a node from a list affects printing the node ... why? It's the list that was changed; printing the list omits the deleted node, as one would expect.

Comment: Why do people downvote things without explanation? What is wrong with this question? The OP provided the code and explained what he is confused about ... what else should he have done?

Comment: by freeing something a pointer points to free(ptr), the pointer ptr still points to the previously allocated now deallocated memory. If you derefence the pointer it may or may not work since it is undefined behavior.

Comment: I think you should modify your function 
`void deleteNode(struct lnode** head, struct lnode* node)` to 
`struct lnode* deleteNode(struct lnode** head, struct lnode* node)` and then return the head node always.

In that case, if you want to delete the head node. You should return the next node after your deleted the head node.

Comment: @RajTendulkar that would be a nice solution if it were possible. Unfortunately, it is not. This is a university project and function headers cannot be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you expecting that printf of a node to do? Why are you expecting removing something from a list to affect the printing of the thing removed?

Other than the fact that it frees the node, deleting the node from the list isn't relevant ... you're printing the node, not the list. The node you're printing is the one you `free`d, which is undefined behavior. There's no way to know what behavior might be. For your implementation, it happens to print the node's value it had before you `free`d it, but you can't count on that or anything like it.

Edit:

> The autograder is telling me that I failed to free all used memory.

You allocate memory for the word but you never free it, you only free the node. You should replace your two free calls with freeNode, and write freeNode that frees any memory owned by the node, in this case free(node->word) and free(node).

Comment: I thought by `free`ing the node, it would spit out an error if I tried to access one of the structure's members.

Comment: @MattAltepeter What is "it"? C is a low-level language that was originally designed for machines with only a few K (not M or G) of memory; there are no extra moving parts, no watchdogs. If you access free'd memory, all bets are off. If you store or read from outside an array, all bets are off. If you wonder why anyone would teach or learn such a language in this day and age ... me too.

Comment: P.S. You should think about what it would take to spit out an error for any access of any field of a deleted struct. How would that be detected? Remember, there's no magic in the computer ... everything that happens, happens algorithmically.

Comment: @MattAltepeter P.P.S. You wrote "It works perfectly, unless the node to be deleted is the head" ... but surely it doesn't spit out an error if you delete some other node and then try to print it. What is the different behavior you see when deleting the head node and deleting other nodes? You never said.

Comment: When I refer to "it" I mean the compiler. I thought I would get a seg fault or something along those lines. And I guess there isn't any difference when I do it. This is actually a university project and we have an autograder that tells me I failed to free all used memory when I submit my code.

Comment: @MattAltepeter You would only get a segfault if the physical memory had been uncoupled from the virtual address and returned to the OS, but that can only be done per-page, not for small allocations, and most mallocs don't do it at all because it's too costly (slow). And your question should have been about the message from the autograder: when you free your node, you don't free the string it points to. Now you should consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `nodeGetWord` just extracts the text string from the node passed to it, which is why it still prints the correct string after you remove the node. It doesn't look at the list at all.

You do however have another and more serious error though, and that is that you access the node `e` *after* you free'd it in `deleteNode`. This is *undefined behavior* and is a bad thing.